# Transform snake_case to camelCase with sed

Tags: regex, sed

I want to convert `my_long_variable` to `myLongVariable` in sed.

This works:

```
echo "my_long_variable" | sed -r 's/(^|_)([a-z])/\U\2/g' | sed -r 's/^(.)/\l\1/g'
```

Is there a more elegant way to do that with sed?

Answer (score 7):

First of all, [prefer `-E` to `-r`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/310446/135943); it's more portable.

However, since you're using the `\U` GNU extension in any case, this isn't that crucial.

Second, I assume `echo` is a stand-in for a more complex command.  If there is in fact no complex command, consider using a [Here String or a Here Doc](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/HereDocument) instead.

Crucially, you don't need to fire up two Sed processes just to run two Sed commands.  Sed is a complete programming language in itself.  Just separate the two commands with a semicolon: `sed 's/foo/bar/;s/frip/baz/'`

However, in this case you don't even need that, because you only need a single substitution.

```
sed -E 's/_([a-z])/\U\1/g' <<< my_long_variable
```

---

There is another aspect here.  You shouldn't often need to change case *in scripts* (and certainly not in Bash).  But if you're doing this in your editor, you should use `vi` rather than a Bash script for the editing.  `\U` and its relatives *are* standard features of `vi`, though not of Sed.

So within `vi`, on a line of text containing only the variable name, you can use:

```
:s/_\([a-z]\)/\U\1/g
```

This is portable ([POSIX compliant](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/vi.html)) and will work on *any* system that has `vi`, even the most minimal implementation.

Comment: Thanks! This is part of a code generation tool (with different modules using different languages with different conventions), so vi won't do, it needs to be automated.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul, gotcha!  For scripted text edits, you may want to learn `ex` (the predecessor of `vi`), which is *designed* for editing text files (whereas Sed is the **s**tream **ed**itor)—and is [fully portable](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html).  I've [written extensively on its use](http://unix.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a135943%20ex) on the Unix & Linux Stack Exchange.

Comment: The vi command `:s/_\([a-z]\)/\U\1/g` fails to convert the first character of the variable name to upper case. (Edit: I guess that's what OP desired.)

Answer (score 6):

Why try to match for `(^|_)`? You are anyway modifying it at the end, so just skip the first character entirely:

```
echo "my_long_variable" | sed -r 's/_([a-z])/\U\1/gi' | sed -r 's/^([A-Z])/\l\1/'
```

The above pattern will take care of cases where you start with:

```
Some_var_Iable
```

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the other good suggestions, don't pipe sed to another invocation of sed, use a semi-colon to separate multiple commands.

Also you might want to make your `toCamelCase` method more generic, e.g.

```
echo "Something_with-a bit_of Variety" | sed -E 's/[ _-]([a-z])/\U\1/gi;s/^([A-Z])/\l\1/'
```

outputs

```
somethingWithABitOfVariety
```

or even

```
echo "Something & some_special! chars" | sed -E 's/[^a-z]+([a-z])/\U\1/gi;s/^([A-Z])/\l\1/'
```

outputs

```
somethingSomeSpecialChars
```

Comment: Semicolons are not portable to anything other than GNU `sed`. You can use `-e` to append more editing commands at the end, which is the portable way to do it. Other than that, welcome and good first post!

Comment: Fair point, but then neither is `\U`!

Comment: Not using multiple `sed` processes *was* already mentioned in [Wildcard's answer](/a/147378).

Comment: @TobySpeight you are correct - somehow I missed that! Should I downvote myself for skim reading?! Perhaps I should edit my answer just to demonstrate the general conversion to camel case from any string with special chars etc.